# Format Filesystem to work with separate boot and data drives

Tags: filesystem

I am building a PC and was going to use a small SSD to hold my OS and a larger hard drive to store my files on.  I was wondering if there was any way for me to move my home folder or mess with my partitions so it wouldn't just store everything on the SSD and I could actually use the data drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start the Ubuntu installation, and in the partition menu, choose "Other" and do exactly what you said :

- Create an EXT4 partition on the SSD, with a `/` mountpoint.
- Create an EXT4 partition on the DATA drive, with a `/home` mountpoint.
- You can also use a NTFS/FAT partition if you want, and link this disk to your '/home', with a shortcut directly.

PS : `/` and `/home` cannot be NTFS because of the permission used by NTFS being incompatible with the way Linux works. NTFS is indeed a Windows-related format.

Comment: Data actually wasn't an acronym, it was what I was going to put on it.  Thanks anyway, though.  Also, why do you promote EXT4?

Comment: Isn't it the recommended format for an Ubuntu partition ? Dunno, I used it for 2 years now and it works well.

Comment: Ubuntu just formats mine to FAT32 by default.